# MUI ToggleButton set selected background-colour dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

```
const StyledToggleButton = styled(MuiToggleButton)(({ selectedColor }) => ({
    "&.Mui-selected, &.Mui-selected:hover": {
        backgroundColor: selectedColor,
    }
}));
const FilterTeam = (props) => {
  const [view, setView] = useState(1);
  const handleChange = (event: any, nextView: any) => {
    setView(nextView);
  };

  return (
   <ToggleButtonGroup
    orientation="horizontal"
    value={view}
    exclusive
    onChange={handleChange}
   >
    { Object.values(teams).map((teamObject: any, index) =>
     <StyledToggleButton
      key={teamObject.team}
      className={classes.toggleButton}
      value={teamObject.team}
      selectedColor={teamObject.colorTheme}
     >
      <img className={classes.teamLogo}
        alt="team logo" src={teamObject.logo} />
     </StyledToggleButton>
    )}
   </ToggleButtonGroup>
  );
}

export default FilterTeam
```

I keep getting:`Warning: React does not recognize the` selectedColor`prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase`selectedcolor `instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.`. I have gone over a couple sandbox which implement the same but I am trying it on typescript so I am not sure how it converts.
I have referred to https://codesandbox.io/s/69707814-set-selected-color-of-toggle-button-group-mui-5l5lh?file=/demo.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `shouldForwardProp` [option to styled](https://mui.com/system/styled/#api) to prevent the `selectedColor` prop from being forwarded through to `ToggleButton` (which then passes it along to the DOM element).

```
const ToggleButton = styled(MuiToggleButton, {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== "selectedColor"
})(({ selectedColor }) => ({
  "&.Mui-selected, &.Mui-selected:hover": {
    color: "white",
    backgroundColor: selectedColor
  }
}));
```

[image: Edit 69707814/set-selected-color-of-toggle-button-group-mui (forked)]

Emotion documentation: https://emotion.sh/docs/styled#customizing-prop-forwarding

Related answer: [@mui/system -- how to pass transient props to styled()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71128841/mui-system-how-to-pass-transient-props-to-styled/71130344#71130344)

Comment: Thanks I was able to make the change and it works as expected. Another thing which I noticed I had been making a mistake with is that I was importing styled from @mui/styles instead of @mui/system which made all the difference. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71128841/mui-system-how-to-pass-transient-props-to-styled/71130344#71130344 really helped thanks